# Char array to binary array not working

Tags: c, arrays, binary

So I'm trying to make a string to binary method in C. Here is my code so far:

```
int main(int argc, char **argv) {
    convertStringToBits("hello");
}

char *convertStringToBits(char **string) {
    int i;
    int stringLength = strlen(string);
    int mask = 0x80; /* 10000000 */
    char charArray[stringLength * 8]; //* 8 for char bits?

    for(i = 0; i < (sizeof(string) / sizeof(char)) + 1; i++) {
        mask = 0x80;
        char c = string[i];
        while(mask > 0) {
            printf("%d", (c & mask) > 0);
            mask >>= 1; /* move the bit down */
            //add to char array
        }
        printf("\n");
    }

    return charArray;
}
```

The expected output of: `hello` should be:

```
01101000
01100101
01101100
01101100
01101111
```

But i get this:

```
01101000
01101111
01100011
00100000
01011011
```

I also want to return an array of characters but I can't seem to do this.

Thanks for the help!

Comment: `sizeof(char)` is always 1.

Comment: @iharob not on all systems I don't think (e.g. Raspbian)

Comment: It's mandatory by the standard. It MUST be 1. Whether `CHAR_BITS` is 8 or not, that's something else but `sizeof(char)` MUST be 1.

Comment: `int stringLength = (sizeof(string) / sizeof(char)) + 1;` - this will not work as expected

Comment: @EdHeal @iharob It still gives me the same output. Updated code to use `strlen(...)`

Comment: You have many other mistakes.

Comment: 1. It should be `int stringLength = strlen(*string);` - compiler should throw a wobble if all warnings are enabled. 2 Fix it in the `for` loop as well

Comment: Updated the code to show how i use it in main

Comment: Your code is all *UNDEFINED BEHAVIOR*. Please enable compiler warnings and your compiler should kick you in the ... Don't take it the wrong way but your code has a lot of problems for such a little ammount of code.

Comment: Do you have a compiler that doesn't emit warnings or did you ignore them?

Comment: Why not make this very fast for a couple of K and use a look up table?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Oopsie:

```
 char **string
```

You want to pass a string, that is a char *. You're instead passing a pointer to a pointer.

This

```
int stringLength = (sizeof(string) / sizeof(char)) + 1;
```

appears to be working by chance, because `sizeof(string)` returns 4 (the size of a pointer) *on your platform*, and "Hello" is 5 characters. You want

```
int stringLength = strlen(string);
```

This also will not work:

```
char charArray[stringLength * 8]; //* 8 for char bits?
```

because its memory only "lives" inside the function. To pass it outside, you need to allocate it using malloc():

```
char *charArray;
charArray = malloc(8*stringLength+1);
// Check that malloc returned a valid pointer. It's almost certain
// that it will, but the one time it might return NULL...
if (charArray == NULL) {
    // ...you want to know it. Using charArray now would crash.
    printf("An error occurred\n");

    // Either return something harmless or something that will
    // show to the upstream code that an error occurred.
    return NULL;
}
```

Comment: Terrible `NULL == charArray` I can't even look at it. And why don't you use `CHAR_BITS` instead? Also, please read the code carefully.

Comment: @iharob - It is not terrible - it is yoda convention.

Comment: @EdHeal I know, I hate it so much. It's hard for me to understand. I know that it prevents accidental assignment, but it's unnatural to read.

Comment: I see that you picked up on the `**` thing.

Comment: Yes, sorry. And I'm updating the check. Is *Yoda convention* in any way official? I love it :-)

Comment: A matter of taste it is, free are people choose to their preferences. Talking reverse in to understand however diffcult is. But don't change it, it's really just a matter of preference.

Comment: @iharob Make constructive comments. "X is so terrible I can't look at it" is not constructive. Also, it's `CHAR_BIT` (no S)

Comment: This answer fixed my problem! Thank you :)

Comment: @trentcl You are right about the `S` I have a **terrible** memory, It's just a comment and I don't think it's offensive or anything. It's constructive (*appart from the YODA condition part*), I think it helped fixing a problem the answer had. Also, I upvoted this answer because it's better than mine.

Comment: @trentcl , no offense was taken and it's useful to me to know that someone perceives 'Yoda convention' as difficult to read. I don't like reading incomprehensible code, and I'd prefer not to force anyone to do so -- especially if a co-worker, friend, or worse yet, interviewer.

Comment: @iharob The `CHAR_BIT` part was constructive, I just wish you hadn't started out with the other part. I admit I assumed you had downvoted (at the time I saw it, it was at -1 and yours the only comment).

Comment: @trentcl Yes I downvoted, but I didn't downvote for the Yoda thing, rather because there was a mistake. It turned out that the OP was editing ...

Answer (score 4):

Your calculation of `stringLength` is wrong, the `sizeof` is an operator and it gives you the size of a type, objects having array type will of course return the size of the array. But your `string` variable is not an array it's a pointer, and the size of a poitner is not the length of the contents it points to.

Also, I suspect you are doing something else wrong because this

```
char c = string[i];
```

is wrong, the type of `string[i]` is `char *` not `char`.

You didn't post all the code, but those are 2 mistakes in your code. It's not clear why you are passing `char **` to the function if you don't want to alter the parameter.

Comment: It gives me the amount of characters in the string so it is definitely working.

Comment: It's wrong. Don't contradict a more experienced programmer unless you have evidence that they're wrong. If it's correct, why are you adding `1`? and what is the length of the string? Can you change it?

Comment: So how would I calculate stringLength properly then?

Comment: `strlen` - Look it up. `sizeof` is fixed at compile time

Comment: I don't know, you didn't post the code where you pass the `string` to the function. In principle it should be `strlen(*string)`.